# What is the difference between "Total physical memory reserved by individual processes" (Task Manager) and "Used Physical Memory" (Resource Monitor)?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-management

What is the difference between **"Total physical memory reserved by individual processes"** (Task Manager) and **"Used Physical Memory"** (Resource Monitor)?

**"Total physical memory reserved by individual processes" (Task Manager):**

[image: "Total physical memory reserved by individual processes" (Task Manager)]

**"xx% Used Physical Memory" (from Resource Monitor):**

[image: "xx% Used Physical Memory" (from Resource Monitor)]

(screenshots taken in Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/what-is-the-difference-between-total-physical/e39e339a-8ddb-4cc9-a8d5-7667a34b2c8b

"The Total physical memory reserved by individual processes in Task Manager and the Used Physical Memory in Resource Monitor are the same. They both show the total memory that are being consumed by all of the processes. There is a slight difference between the data of Task Manager and Resource Monitor because Task Manager also includes the nonpaged and paged pool. If you want to know more about memory pool, click here. Please take note that link provides complex information about memory pool."